# Redux data dependency management

Tags: reactjs, redux, dependency-management

I'm trying to understand how I should structure my redux application, if i need to retrieve data, from multiple endpoints, that depend on each other.

For example, lets say I have a component that lists event details. I have an event id, and i need to get all the info for that event, and also all the events that occur between the event times. In order for me to know what events to search for i need to get the start and end time of the selected event.

How do I structure a component to handle that? So far I was thinking something like:

```
({event, conflictingEvents,fetchEvent, fetchConflictingEvents}) => {
    if (!event || !conflictingEvents) {
        if (!event) fetchEvent();
        if (!conflictingEvents) fetchConflictingEvents(event.start, event.end)
            return (/* empty state */);
    }
    return (/* actual state */);
```

The problem with the above is that it depends on caching to not create an infinite loop.

Comment: Is this a question about redux, or how to build a component? Also, where does dependency management come into play?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to orchestrate multiple asynchronous HTTP calls and update the state of your application as you go, correct?

---

The idiomatic approach to this task would be to **use [async actions](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html)**. This allows you to trigger the load procedure from your React components via a single dispatch of your asynch action. This async action then coordinates the calls to your backend and the mapping of data between the calls.

You can **dispatch synchronous actions along the way to update the state** of your application as needed, e.g. to display the progress to the user or to show the final result.

As a result, you have **encapsulated the orchestration of your API calls** completely. Neither the React component that renders your application, nor your reducers need to know about the order of the calls, or which information you pass between them. Only the intermediate and final outcome of your calls that should be part of your state is relevant to them.

---

As an alternative to async actions you could also look into **[sagas](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga)**, which take a slightly different approach to the problem.

Comment: this more or less gets at the heart of the problem. I guess I had a narrow view of async actions. I didnt consider that the async action could perform multiple synchronous ajax requests and dispatch synchronous actions along the way.

TLDR: async actions are highly flexible.

Comment: also i would give you another +1 for sagas if I could. I looked into them and they fit the use case of multitiered dependencies well.